# g++: Compiling without -l flags

Tags: c++, linker, libraries

Simple question- are these any way to not have to call libraries during the compiling? I mean, I would like to simply call g++ main.cpp without calling g++ main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lSTL -lMyMother and so on... I know, makefiles or simple shell scripting, but I would like to make it elegant way - call these libraries inside cpp code - something like 'using GL;'.

Comment: No, unlike VC++ there is no way to tell GCC which libraries to link to by specifying it in the source code. Use a makefile.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using GCC, you could create/modify a [specs file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Spec-Files.html) to add the flags you want.

If you don't like typing flags, you really should be using a makefile, though.

Comment: Well I suppose you are right - there is a reason everyone are using Makefiles. ;)

Comment: Don't modify the specs file to add libraries inside them.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can dynamically load libraries by `dlopen()` and call functions from it (I am assuming you are on *nix). Though that would be not the same thing and I doubt will make your life easier. Other than that there is no portable way of specifying which library to use in source file.

Comment: Thanks, gotta try this method. I should only remember that if something won't work it's because my laziness.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you may use [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) and shell expansion. Use `pkg-config --list-all` to discover what packages are known to it (you might add a `.pc` file to add a new package). For instance, a GTK application `mygtkapp.c` could be compiled with

```
gcc -Wall -g $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-x11-3.0) -c mygtkapp.c
```

then later linked with

```
gcc -g mygtkapp.o $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-x11-3.0) -o mygtkapp
```

Notice that order of arguments to `gcc` always matter. Of course use `g++` to compile C++ applications with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Consider also using a `Makefile` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108). Then just type `make` to build your software (and e.g. `make clean` to clean the build tree).

<sup>You might use weird tricks in your `Makefile` to e.g. parse with `awk` some comments in your C++ code to feed `make` but I think it is a bad idea.</sup>

Technically, you still pass `-I` and `-D` flags (at compile time) and `-L` and `-l` flags (at link time) to `gcc` or `g++` but the `pkg-config` utility (or `make` ....) is generating these flags.

If you edit your source code with `emacs` you could add a comment at end of your C file to set some compilation command for `emacs`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7380281/841108).

<sup>PS. I don't recommend configuring your GCC spec files for such purposes.</sup>