# Failed to link program with OpenSSL

Tags: gcc, linker, openssl

This is my compile command

```
gcc msg_utils.o -o mtm -lm -L/openssl-1.0.0a  -lssl -lcrypto
```

I get error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
```

Please tell me what wrong with my command ,the path to openssl is correct ,I get openssl source from :

https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0a.tar.gz

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking OpenSSL libraries to a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352573/linking-openssl-libraries-to-a-program). Also ensure you configured with the `shared` option; see [Compilation and Installation | Configure Options](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I guess you are on Linux)</sup>

You should probably *install* some OpenSSL package in your Linux distribution.

Perhaps `aptitude install libssl-dev` on Debian related distributions.

If you compile OpenSSL from source code, you probably need some `make install` step and you might need to run `ldconfig` after that.

You might want to use [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) during compilation of your code:

```
gcc -Wall -g $(pkg-config -cflags openssl) \
   msg_utils.o -o mtm \
   $(pkg-config -libs openssl)
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639196/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108)